# Writing Python script for Altering Multiple Fields

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, fields-attributes

I'm a novice programmer and I would like to ask for something which will facilitate my work. I need to rename all the field names in some shapefiles I am working on and since renaming is an arduous task, I need to automate using some scripting. Renaming a shapefile field name is not possible so I used geodatabase. Now, the 'Alter Field' tool is limited to only one field name at a time.

Can somebody help me with the script I need?

Below is the example.

Example:

```
arcpy.AlterField_management(r'D:\Workspace\11-30-2014\Approved GDB\Nisma_GIS DATA\2NISMA_WETCO.gdb\NISMA_WETCO\CHAMBER2', 'LOCATION_I', 'LOCATION_ID', 'LOCATION_ID')
```

How can I include these: ('X_COORD', 'X_COORDINATE', 'X_COORDINATE', 'Y_COORD' , 'Y_COORDINATE', 'Y_COORDINATE'...etc)

I tried just putting all in the same code but I got this error:

> TypeError: AlterField() takes at most 4 arguments

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2, Standard (ArcEditor) License.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you'll need to loop, so you first need to create the list of your old and new fields

```
oldfields = ['XCOORD', 'YCOORD']
newfields = ['X_COORDINATE', 'Y_COORDINATE']

for i in range(len(oldfields)):
    arcpy.AlterField_management(r'D:\Workspace\11-30-2014\Approved GDB\Nisma_GIS DATA\2NISMA_WETCO.gdb\NISMA_WETCO\CHAMBER2', oldfields[i], newfields[i], newfields[i])
```

Note that the alias is optional, and that you could use a third list with the aliases if you want your aliases to be different from the field names.

Answer (score 2):

Use a FieldInfo object.

```
# create the object
fieldInfo = arcpy.FieldInfo()
# add field to the filedinfo object
fieldInfo.AddField("OldName", "NewName", "VISIBLE", "NONE") # takes 4 args
# can do this for any number of fields, all added to the fieldInfo object.
# then use Make table or featureclass view, using the fieldInfo object.
# then copy out
```

see here :
[FieldInfo help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z0000004v000000)

I used this script to reformat a whole bunch of tables in a mdb.
The header had multiple space, % & * in them. AlterField couldn't handle this but using FieldInfo worked.

```
tbls = arcpy.ListTables()

for tbl in tbls:
    t1 = time.time()
    tblValid = arcpy.ValidateTableName(tbl)
    outTbl = os.path.join(HomeDir, Outdb, tblValid)
    fieldInfo = arcpy.FieldInfo()
    # print "Old {}  New {}".format(tbl, tblValid)
    fNames = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(tbl)]
    for f in fNames:
        fTemp = f.strip()
        if "%" in fTemp:
            fTemp = fTemp.replace("%", "_pc")
        if "*" in fTemp:
            fTemp = fTemp.replace("*", "")
        if " " in fTemp:
            fTemp = fTemp.replace(" ", "")
        if "__" in fTemp:
            fTemp - fTemp.replace("__", "_")
        fValid = arcpy.ValidateFieldName(fTemp)
        # print "{}  {}".format(fTemp, fValid)
        fieldInfo.addField(f, fValid, "VISIBLE", "NONE")
    arcpy.MakeTableView_management(tbl, tbl + "_vw", "", "", fieldInfo)
    if arcpy.Exists(outTbl):
        arcpy.Delete_management(outTbl)
    arcpy.CopyRows_management(tbl + "_vw", outTbl)
```